# webdriver.chome() not callable or selenium.webdriver.chrome' has no attribute 'get'

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I try to open a web page but failed in either case. I got the same error under both the Phycharm and PyhIDE. Please help

case (a)

```python
from selenium import webdriver
web = webdriver.chrome()
web.get("www.google.com")
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```python
File "C:\Users\kj\PycharmProjects\NHS\NHS.py", line 2, in <module>
    web = webdriver.chrome()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

case (b)

```python
from selenium import webdriver
web = webdriver.chrome("c:\python\chromedriver.exe")
web.get("www.google.com")
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```python
  File "C:\Users\kj\PycharmProjects\NHS\NHS.py", line 2, in <module>
    web = webdriver.chrome()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

case(c)

```python
from selenium import webdriver
web = webdriver.chrome
web.get("www.google.com")
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```python
  File "C:\Users\kj\PycharmProjects\NHS\NHS.py", line 3, in <module>
    web.get("www.google.com")
AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver.chrome' has no attribute 'get'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to uppercase first letter of "chrome" so that it would be

```python
web = webdriver.Chrome()
```

Comment: Many many thanks